# Why use B tree for database index other than AVL tree

Tags: database, indexing, data-structures

I heard some statements like, consider the height of the AVL tree and the maximum keys that an AVL tree node can contain, the search of AVL tree will be time-consuming because of the disk io.
However, imagine that an index file contains the whole AVL tree structure, and then the size of the index file is less than a fan size, we can just read the whole AVL tree in only once disk io.

It seems like using AVL tree does not bring about extra disk io, how do you explain B tree is better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> we can just read the whole AVL tree in only once disk io

Yes, it could work like that. Essentially, the whole data structure would be brought into memory. IO would no longer be a concern.

Some databases use this strategy. For example, SQL Server In-Memory "Hekaton" does this and delivers ~100x the normal throughput for OLTP.

Hekaton uses two index data structues: hash tables and trees. I think the trees are called cw-trees and are similar to b-trees.

For general purpose database workloads it is very desirable to not need everything in memory. B-trees are a great design tradeoff in those cases.

Answer (score 0):

Databases use balanced binary trees(plus) avl is only a special case of these balanced trees, so there is no need for it

Answer (score 0):

Its coz B-Trees usually have larger number of keys in single node and hence reducing the depth of the search, in record indexing the link traversal time is longer if the depth is more, hence for cache locality and making the tree wider than deeper, multiple keys are stored in array of a node which improves cache performance and quick lookup comparatively.